# How do a get a connection string that uses windows authenication to work without windows authenication?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=MyDBName;Data Source=MyServerName

this is the connection string, it can not be changed, it is in a dll from the dark ages. we are having to use it on a server outside of our domain. we can hit the server because we set up a host entry all we need is read access is there something on the sql server that can be configured to allow this connection?

but get the following:
Message: Login failed for user '(null)'. Reason: Not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.
Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either

1. Configure the app to run in the context of a Windows user who has sufficient permissions to the data on the SQL Server or
2. Create a Windows login on the SQL Server for the user(s) whose accounts the app is running under.

Comment: i tried enabling impersonation in asp.net but got an error that the domain could not resolved.

Comment: You need to make sure that the application pool in IIS that is servicing your app is running with its identity set to that of the Windows account that has access to your db.